# mysql Função Rank agrupada para um COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Tenho 3 tabelas no MYSQL aqui representadas como exemplo:

[image: Tabelas]

Preciso de uma query que me devolva um RANK de contratos efetuados agrupado por comercial num dado período de tempo, por exemplo:

Uma query que me devolva o RANK dos comerciais entre `2016-01-01` e `2016-01-03`, deveria ficar assim:

[image: Como deve ficar]

Já tentei várias soluções mas nenhuma retorna o resultado que necessito, por exemplo um ponto importante é quando o comercial tem o mesmo número de contratos deve ter a mesma posição no ranking, neste exemplo o comercial Com1 e o Com2 têm a posição 1 no Ranking porque ambos têm 2 contratos no período escolhido.

**O meu query atualmente é:**

```
    set @rn:=0,@grp:=0,@prevdate:='';
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumContratos, NomeCom,NomeEmp
     , ( select count(*)+1
           from (
                select IdComercial
                     , count(*) as c
                  from contratos
                group
                    by IdComercial
                ) as m
          where c >
                (
                select count(*) 
                  from contratos as e

                 where e.IdComercial = T.IdComercial
                )
       ) AS Rank
     , T.IdComercial AS IdCom
  FROM contratos AS T

INNER JOIN comerciais ON T.IdComercial=comerciais.IdComercial
INNER JOIN empresas ON T.IdEmpresa=empresas.IdEmpresa

WHERE (DataContrato BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-03')

GROUP 
    BY T.IdComercial
ORDER
    BY Rank
```

**E esse é o script de criação do banco de dados, tabela e inserção dos dados:**

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         localhost
-- Server version:               10.1.9-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
-- Server OS:                    Win32
-- HeidiSQL Version:             9.2.0.4947
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

-- Dumping database structure for teste
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `teste` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `teste`;


-- Dumping structure for table teste.comerciais
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comerciais` (
  `IdComercial` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IdEmpresa` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NomeCom` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdComercial`),
  KEY `IdEmpresa` (`IdEmpresa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Dumping data for table teste.comerciais: ~5 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `comerciais` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `comerciais` (`IdComercial`, `IdEmpresa`, `NomeCom`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Com1'),
    (2, 1, 'Com2'),
    (3, 2, 'Com3'),
    (4, 2, 'Com4'),
    (5, 4, 'Com5');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `comerciais` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table teste.contratos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contratos` (
  `IdContratos` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IdComercial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DataContrato` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdContratos`),
  KEY `IdComercial` (`IdComercial`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Dumping data for table teste.contratos: ~5 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `contratos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `contratos` (`IdContratos`, `IdComercial`, `DataContrato`) VALUES
    (1, 1, '2016-01-01'),
    (2, 1, '2016-01-01'),
    (3, 2, '2016-01-02'),
    (4, 3, '2016-01-02'),
    (5, 4, '2016-01-03');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `contratos` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table teste.empresas
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empresas` (
  `IdEmpresa` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NomeEmp` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdEmpresa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Dumping data for table teste.empresas: ~5 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `empresas` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `empresas` (`IdEmpresa`, `NomeEmp`) VALUES
    (1, 'Emp1'),
    (2, 'Emp2'),
    (3, 'Emp3'),
    (4, 'Emp4'),
    (5, 'Emp5');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `empresas` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

O que me devolve não é coerente com o que necessito, por exemplo, devolve-me um rank onde por exemplo falta a posição **6** (no caso da minha base de dados)

Comment: Olhando meio por cima eu chuto que seu `INNER JOIN` está fazendo a posição 6 sumir. Mude os 2 `INNER JOIN` para `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: resultado igual.

Comment: Tá, você consegue colocar os `creates` e `inserts` da tabela pra podermos testar as `querys`?

Comment: Desculpe, ainda sou novo aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta. Talvez algum comercial que não tenha contrato não apareça na relação, aí precisaremos fazer uma leve alteração.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua `query` ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT x.IdComercial,
       x.NomeCom,
       emp.NomeEmp,
       CASE x.quantidade
           when @curQtd then @curRank
           else @curRank := @curRank + 1
       END AS Rank,
       CASE @curQtd
            when x.quantidade then @curQtd := quantidade
            else @curQtd := x.quantidade
       END AS NumContratos
  FROM (SELECT com2.IdComercial,
               com2.NomeCom,
               com2.IdEmpresa,
               COUNT(1) AS quantidade
         FROM comerciais com2
              INNER JOIN contratos con2 ON con2.IdComercial = com2.IdComercial
         GROUP BY com2.IdComercial) x
       INNER JOIN empresas emp ON x.IdEmpresa = emp.IdEmpresa
       JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0, @curQtd := 0) r -- Aqui apenas zeramos os valores iniciais
 ORDER BY x.quantidade DESC
```

O último `JOIN` é para zerar as variáveis e o primeiro é para obter as quantidades. Note que as variáveis são incrementadas de acordo com as regras do case e apenas são alteradas caso a quantidade seja alterada conforme a linha anterior.

Caso queira mostrar mesmo os comerciais que não possuem contratos, você deve utilizar `LEFT JOIN` que ainda assim trará o registro, mesmo que o outro não exista, e colocar a coluna `IdContratos` no `COUNT` assim, os comerciais sem contrato terão a somatória correta:

```
SELECT x.IdComercial,
       x.NomeCom,
       emp.NomeEmp,
       CASE x.quantidade
           when @curQtd then @curRank
           else @curRank := @curRank + 1
       END AS Rank,
       CASE @curQtd
            when x.quantidade then @curQtd := quantidade
            else @curQtd := x.quantidade
       END AS NumContratos
  FROM (SELECT com2.IdComercial,
               com2.NomeCom,
               com2.IdEmpresa,
               COUNT(con2.IdContratos) AS quantidade
         FROM comerciais com2
              LEFT JOIN contratos con2 ON con2.IdComercial = com2.IdComercial
         GROUP BY com2.IdComercial) x
       INNER JOIN empresas emp ON x.IdEmpresa = emp.IdEmpresa
       JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0, @curQtd := 0) r -- Aqui apenas zeramos os valores iniciais
 ORDER BY x.quantidade DESC
```

Comment: Funciona na perfeição. Obrigado @Sorack. Uma de Mestre.

Comment: @PauloRosa veja só se a situação que te falei não vai atrapalhar. Quando você tiver algum comercial sem contratos

Comment: Quando tenho comerciais sem contratos não aparecem de facto esses comerciais, mas deviam aparecer com 0 contratos.

Comment: @PauloRosa adicionei um segundo exemplo que irá se encaixar nesse problema

Comment: Fabuloso. Obrigado @Sorack